# Customizing output of datasource in repeater?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datatable, datasource, datarepeater

I have a Data Repeater hooked up to a datasource (datatable object). I need to change the output on the frontend for certain columns under certain conditions. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

I am currently trying to create the formatted output and assign it to another datatable and use that as the data source, but it seems overly complicated and something that would be hard to maintain.

Is there an easier way to manipulate column values for a datasource? I need the ability to check the previous and next rows for the source as that is a basis for some of the column values.

Comment: What kind of manipulation are you talking about? Are we talking about formatting dates, or something more complicated?

Comment: Changing column values (strings) based on previous and next row values

Comment: Hmm... sounds like it might be a good candidate for the `ItemDataBound` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about simple manipulation, the `DataBinder.Eval` method accepts a format string:

```
<%#Eval("SomeMoneyColumn", "{0:C}")%>
```

If the format string is not sufficient, you could create a method in the code-behind to handle the formatting, like this:

```
<%#FormatData(Eval("SomeColumn"))%>
```

In code-behind:

```
protected string FormatData(object data)
{
    return String.Format("My name is {0}", data);
}
```

You can also use the `ItemDataBound` event too. Using this technique, you can still access the datasource object, in the case that your manipulation involves other data that is bound to the repeater.

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblCtrl = e.Item.FindControl("SomeControl") as Label;
    if (lblCtrl != null)
    {
        lblCtrl.Text = String.Format("My name is {0}", DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "SomeColumn"));
    }
}
```

Comment: So I could get the entire datasource in the itemdatabound event?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do what you want on the client side easily w/o using special logic like you are doing now. If you are getting data from a database, you could potentially do all the data manipulation on the DB side and pass it along transparently to the front end.